# How to prove the spectrality of valuation spectrum of a commutative ring?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, valuation-theory

Please help me to understand the proof of spectrality of valuation spectrum of a commutative ring. I'm trying to understand the proposition 4.7 in page 25 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.05934.pdf).
Sorry I spent a lot of time on this proof but I really can't understand.

1. How do these topologies are defined over $SPV(A)$ and why the clopen subsets of the topology induced by $P(A\times A)$ are of the form $SPV(A)(f/s)$?
2. How the topology induced by $P(A\times A)$ is defined? (What are the open sets here?)
3. Why $SPV(A)$ is $T_0$? (How is the open sun set containing one of $f$ or $s$ but not the other one defined?)

Comment: I might try to write a detailed answer in the next days (although 3 months have passed, it might be useful in the future). For now, I can say that Sophie Morel's notes on adic spaces treat the above with much more detail.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll check it out, thank you very much if you do...